# I get a 404 only in firefox/IE while Chrome/Safari works fine

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, web, http-status-code-404, typo3

I found a strange behaviour in firefox. While everything works fine with Chrome, firefox leads to 404 page on most links. So the main URL works, but subdirectory like url.com/news/ not.  When I use private mode in firefox it works. When I clear the cache it works for like 1min then starts failing again.
I checked Add-Ons in firefox (only skype click to call was active and I disabled it). Firefox version is 38.0.5

The page itself runs with typo3, the URLs are fetched with realURL. Also, the site was moved to a news server. I don't find anything in the error log.

Same problem in IE11.

I installed http://www.charlesproxy.com/ as it is suggested in an other thread. But I can not see anything besides that when I want to open /de/news/ all I see is a request to /error/404.

Any idea what it could be or where to start to search?

Comment: Is it unclear in my question? I mentioned that I cleared the cache and then it works for like 1min, but after that falls back to bad behaviour. - Not only on my pc.

Comment: I've got the same problem. No clue, why this is coming, though :(